# Lubuntu 14.04 doesn't list my network

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, hp, 32-bit

I have tried to open `nm-applet` but it doesn't list my/any networks. I thus can't connect to the internet.

```
 $ lspci | grep -i Network
 network controller: Broadcom corporation BCM4321 802.lla/b/g/n  (rev 03)
```

I installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a "HP Pavilion Entertainment PC" laptop.

What do I need to do to connect to my network?

Comment: Wat Kind of DSL-connection is avaible for you? LAN-W-LAN?
Wat Kind of Router Used you?. Sorry my Dear You must correctly ask, to get a right answer. Sometime I had the same Problem in askin, like you. Fritz (freddysblog) from Germany

Comment: First tell us what network connector do you have on your computer. That's the equivalent of telling us the output of: lspci | grep -i Network

Comment: nm-applet doesent list my network @MadMike

Comment: @user281916 did you configure your router to hide the SSID?

Comment: @Smile4ever This is the output of lspci|grep -i Network: `network controller: Broadcom corporation BCM4321 802.lla/b/g/n  (rev 03)`

Comment: Try the comment above from MadMike first :)

Comment: I installed the drivers (with my mobile broadband usb) and now everything works fine, Thank you everyone for helping

Comment: Don't add [solved] to title or in body of your question even when you got a solution. Thanks